# Mongoose query always returns an empty array, though there are records

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code in Node.JS:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = () => {
    const password = 'my-password-here-masked';
    const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://mkreyn:${password}@youtube-base.7mpecw5.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

    const clientOptions = { serverApi: { version: '1', strict: true, deprecationErrors: true } };
   
    try {
    /*  mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        tls: true
      }); */

      mongoose.connect(connectionString, clientOptions)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    const dbConnection = mongoose.connection;
    dbConnection.once("open", (_) => {
      console.log(`Database connected: ${connectionString}`);
    });
   
    dbConnection.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(`connection error: ${err}`);
    });
//    return;

}


const getRecords = async () => {
  
  const AuthorsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    author_name: String,
    author_country: String
  });

  const AuthorsModel = mongoose.model("authors", AuthorsSchema);
  try {
    // Use `find` if you expect multiple records
    const allRecs = await AuthorsModel.find({author_country: "UK" }).exec();
    console.log(allRecs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching records:', error);
  } finally {
    // Close the connection after handling the records
    mongoose.connection.close();
  }
}

const greatFunc = async () => {
  await connectDB();
  await getRecords();
}

greatFunc();
```

This code keeps returning an empty array. There are records which should be returned in reply to such a query. I don't understand, what am I doing wrong here. Please note, that in Node I am a complete beginner, but would like to become eventually full-stack developer (MERN-stack).

Please also note, that I'm not sure if the field "_id" should really be included in the model. I have tried to exclude it, but the result remains intact — I keep getting an empty array.

So, I'm expecting 2 records to be returned, instead I keep getting an empty array, as though there were absolutely no records in the collection.

Comment: The `_id` field is automatically added by mongoose when you create/insert a document. It is best to just omit it from our schema unless you need to assign a different data type to it other than `ObjectId`. An empty array means your database was queried but no match was found. What is the name of your collection? Mongoose infers this from your model.

Comment: Also what is your database name? You don't have it specified in your connection string or are you just connecting to the `test` database?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was indeed because I have not stated the actual database with which to work, only the cluster.